# VBA With Microsoft Access - Check if object exists

Tags: ms-access, vba, activex, webbrowser-control

I'm using VBA with Microsoft Access.

I'm setting an object to an item inside a WebBrowserControl that sometimes exists, sometimes doesn't.

```
Dim myWebBrowser As Object
Dim myItemInsideWebpage As Object

Set myWebBrowser = Me.WebBrowser0.Object
Set myItemInsideWebpage = myWebBrowser.Document.GetElemendById("myDiv")
```

If 'myDiv' exists, awesome, if not I want Access to let me know so I can deal with it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe it would be something like

```
If myItemInsideWebpage Is Nothing Then
' doesn't exist
Else
' does exist
End If
```

You may need to preface your 'Set' statement with 'On Error Resume Next' in case an error is thrown when 'myDiv' does not exist.